# Iterate over only the n-th element of a list of lists, and double nested for?

Tags: python, list, nested-loops

I'm getting data from an excel file, where one columns is basically the team_1 (home team) , the other is team_2 (away team) , and the third column is a number, that corresponds to a day they play.

What I want to check is that in any given day the difference between the home games played and  for each couple I will chose, should be at max a given number (our input, let's say 2 )

```
differ = 2
teams = [0,1,2,3,4,5]
```

I have thought to create a list with  [home_team,day]

```
home=[[1,0],[3,0],[4,0],[1,1],[4,1],[5,1],[1,2],[2,2],[1,3],[2,3],[0,3],[1,4],[0,4],[3,4],[2,5],[5,5],[4,5]]
```

And then sort the list by the day (2nd element of each list)

```
new_p_home = sorted(home, key=lambda x: x[0])
```

now, I also have a random pairs of teams:

```
pairs = [[2, 0], [2, 1], [2, 4], [2, 3], [2, 5], [0, 1], [0, 4], [0, 3], [0, 5], [1, 4], [1, 3], [1, 5], [4, 3], [4, 5], [3, 5]]
```

So want to search through 0 to whatever the day is (let's say it's 10 days) , and for each of the pairs above [2,0],[2,1],etc, to check that in any given day , while it would be 5th day or 10th day, the difference between the home games they have played won't be more than differ.

Now, not only I'm not sure if i iterate correctly for the 1st element of each list of lists, but I surely overcounting.

Any ideas? Any other, smarter way to approach?

```
home_team = [a[0] for a in new_p_home]
hometeam1=0
hometeam2=0
for i in range(0,11):
    for pair in pairs:
        if pair[0] in home_team: 
            hometeam1 = hometeam1 + 1
        if pair[1] in home_team:
            hometeam2 = hometeam2 + 1
print(hometeam1, hometeam2)
```

> answer :  165, 165 ???

Comment: Why aren't you using `i` in the loop?

Comment: `key=lambda x: x[0]` is sorting by the team number, not the day.

Comment: Why aren't you using `differ` anywhere?

Comment: Where does `165` come from? All your team numbers are small numbers.

Comment: Why does the list need to be sorted?

Comment: I'm completely lost as to what you're trying to do here. You're overwriting the `hometeam1` and `hometeam2` variables every time through the loop when the conditions match. So at the end you'll just get the last teams that matched the conditions.

Comment: You're never counting the number of home games played anywhere.

Comment: @barmar
1)you are right, i aint
2)Oh ~ I totally mixed everything here. Yes, the lambda was wrong. 
3) 165 is the answer I get.
4) the number of hometeam1 and hometeam2 were supposed to be the counter of the home games of each team of the pair

Comment: Oops, I totally misread the assignments in the loop. I thought you were assigning team numbers.

Comment: Obviously because I have done something wrong in the loops. I have totally mixed them up in my mind.

Comment: You're counting the number of times any team has played at home. And you're counting all of them every day, not a specific day `i`.

Comment: So you're just multiplying the counts by 11.

Comment: Pandas would probably be a good tool for this, as you can use its grouping and counting functions.

Comment: But how I canNOT do it? This is where I'm having it mixed.  I just want, for each pair of teams, to have a "balanced" home games ratio , aka not more than the "differ". Eg. team 2 can't have 8 home games by day 10, while team 0 has 5. 
Maybe , this can be done without loops (or lists?) at all ?

Comment: Use `collections.Counter()` to get a count for each team.

Comment: Oh, ok, thank you !

Comment: @Barmar, I did so, and i have the occurence of each team in the home games list, but, I still can't find how to count - at any day. I mean, i want to count the occurence, up until day 5 , or 8, not for the whole game, list.